# Holding a button + pressing another macro

Tags: autohotkey

I'm so used to VI-style navigation on my Mac laptop, that I hated everytime when I needed to switch to my Windows machine at home. And I felt miserable until I've discovered "Autohotkey". It's quite powerful. However, I still can't figure out one thing I have in OS X with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

**"HJLK" navigation with "s" button**. So I would hold `s` and press `h` while holding it - cursor goes left, for `j` - it goes down, and etc.

Can I have something like that with Autohotkey? I know it's probably possible using `Ctrl` or `Alt`, but I want `s` button to act like a "special" button. Also remember, it has to be "navigation" - you shouldn't have to let `s` go to switch direction. Pressing `jjj` and then `h`, while holding `s` should move cursor three times down and one time to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apersand symbol for combining two keys. [Documentation](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm) says:

> &     An ampersand may be used between any two keys or mouse buttons to combine them into a custom hotkey.

```
s & h::
    send {left}
return
s & j::send {down}
s & k::send {right}
s & i::send {up}
```

should do

If you want to toggle the effect of the above hotkeys, you can either define them with the `Hotkey` command instead ([link](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm)), or, more easily, use [context-sensitive hotkeys](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_If.htm):

```
^t:: ; your toggle hotkey
    navigation_keys_active := ! navigation_keys_active ; toggle
return

#if navigation_keys_active
s & h::send {left}
; ... etc
#if
```

Also, if you don't want the original key function to be overridden at all, you [can use the `~` tilde operator instead.](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols)

> When the hotkey fires, its key's native function will not be blocked (hidden from the system).

Comment: This will block the single `s` key so you won't be able to type it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
$i::HkHelperFunc("s", "{Up}", "i")
$h::HkHelperFunc("s", "{Left}", "h")
$j::HkHelperFunc("s", "{Down}", "j")
$k::HkHelperFunc("s", "{Right}", "k")

HkHelperFunc(key, keyIfKeyDown, keyIfKeyUp) {
    If GetKeyState(key)
        SendInput, {BS}%keyIfKeyDown%
    Else
        SendInput, %keyIfKeyUp%
}
```

Alternatively, maybe a bit cleaner because no characters have to be deleted:

```
$s::  
    sDown := True
    Input, L, L1 T0.3
    If (sDown && (L = "I" || L = "H" || L = "J" || L = "L"))
        traytip ;do nothing
    Else If (ErrorLevel != "Timeout")
        SendInput, s%L%
Return

$s UP::
    sDown := False
Return

#If sDown
i::SendInput, {Up}
h::SendInput, {Left}
j::SendInput, {Down}
k::SendInput, {Right}
```

Comment: at first it seemed to work, but then sometimes it wouldn't recognize "s" being pressed by itself.